# How to authenticate each API for authorize user?

Tags: node.js, authentication, redis, authorization, roles

I would like to authorize users for each api call.
For example:
`app.post('/user', isAuth('user.write'), controller);`

Above api requires `user.write` role, so how to check everytime that user has this role or not? isAuth function validates that user.

As per me we can save all the users roles at the time of login into redis and in each api call we fetch it from redis.

But roles are more then 1500, won't it make it heavy? Or should I check database for each api?

Or any other better way so I can easily validate each api for user?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize [JWT tokens](https://jwt.io/).

Your API would then issue a JWT token to a user that has the roles.

The user then provides this token for every request, and you don't have to make calls to redis, because you just just decode the JWT token and check out the roles from there.

The JWT token is signed by the server, and can't be modified by the client so you know that the roles are the roles actually provided from the server.

Read more about JWT security in [this article](https://www.notion.so/What-makes-JSON-Web-Tokens-JWT-secure-dca6e0e280474f12ab6cec29939506f6)

A popular library for working with JWT tokens in node is [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) which has over 10000 stars on GitHub.

Comment: But I need to store this JWT somewhere, in Node local memory I can't store as it is microservice, so will node be available to servers, and can't store in cookies as well, as jwt size will be more because of  more then 1500 roles data. So only option left with me is to store it in redis so I can access it anywhere.

Or is there any other better way?

Comment: @ATULSHARMA From the server side you should never store a JWT token. Every request from the client should just include this token. However if there are users with over 1000 roles the JWT payload will likely be quite big. Using a JWT token reduces the load on the database (redis) since you will never have to contact it for authentication or role-checking, but it also increases the overall size of the request

Comment: In cookies we are not able to more then 4KB, and JWT is making it of more then 60 KB which can not be passed in a header as well. So I'm planing to store it in redis. It is microservice, so can't store it in local storage as well. So, Let me know any other better approach for this.